# While loop inside a .then() async

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I recently came across an interesting problem that I cannot solve for the life of me. I am calling an API call that is breaking up records into pages, the info for the pages reside in the response header. From that, I wanted to be able to do another call to retrieve the data and the next header, until there are no more response headers.

```
let parents = {};

const options = {
  credentials: "same-origin",
  headers: {
    accept: "application/json"
  },
  timeout: 5000
};
fetch(
  `/api/v1/courses/200003/enrollments?enrollment_type=ObserverEnrollment&per_page=100`,
  options
).then(response =>
  response
    .json()
    .then(data => ({
      data: data,
      ok: response.ok,
      headers: response.headers
    }))
    .then(res => {
      parents = res;

      nextURL(res.headers.get("Link"));

      let optionsNext = {
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json"
        },
        timeout: 5000
      };
      fetch(nextURL(res.headers.get("Link")), optionsNext).then(response =>
        response
          .json()
          .then(data => ({
            data: data,
            ok: response.ok,
            headers: response.headers
          }))
          .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
              parents.data.push(res.data);
              console.info(parents);
            }
          })
      );
    })
);

function nextURL(linkTxt) {
        let url = null;
        if (linkTxt) {
          let links = linkTxt.split(",");
          let nextRegEx = new RegExp('^<(.*)>; rel="next"$');

          for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            let matches = nextRegEx.exec(links[i]);
            if (matches) {
              url = matches[1];
            }
          }
        }
        return url;
      }
```

The part that I need to put into some kind of loop is the secondary fetch based upon the return of the nextURL function: `if !nextURL(res.headers.get("Link"))` I need to `break` the loop.

```
let optionsNext = {
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
          accept: "application/json"
        },
        timeout: 5000
      };
      fetch(nextURL(res.headers.get("Link")), optionsNext).then(response =>
        response
          .json()
          .then(data => ({
            data: data,
            ok: response.ok,
            headers: response.headers
          }))
          .then(res => {
            if (res.ok) {
              parents.data.push(res.data);
              console.info(parents);
            }
          })
      );
```

Thanks in advance for even looking at my pitiful problem

Comment: You don't really need a while loop, you should use recursion. When the first `fetch` resolves, check if there's a next page, if there is, rerun the function. You really just need a dispatcher object so that you can call the fetch method recursively.

Comment: thank God. I could use a bit more hand holding though @user1538301. Could you please expound a bit more.

Comment: I'm attempting to put together an example, though it won't be a working one (don't know the API you're using lol), one moment.

Comment: TY, it is the Canvas API BTW, https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.pagination.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using recursion; something like this:

```js
const getFetcher = () => ({
    aggregate: [],
    run: function (url, options) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            fetch(url, options)
                .then(response => {
                    const json = response.json();
                    const { headers, data } = response;
                    const nextLink = res.headers.get("Link");
                    this.aggregate.push(data);
                    if (nextLink) {
                        this.run(nextLink, options).then(resolve);
                    }
                    else {
                        resolve(this.aggregate);
                    }
                })

        })
    }
})
const options = {
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
        accept: "application/json"
    },
    timeout: 5000
};
const fetcher = getFetcher();
fetcher.run(`/api/v1/courses/200003/enrollments?enrollment_type=ObserverEnrollment&per_page=100`, options)
    .then(allPagesData => {
        /* at this point you have all the pages data */
    })
```

Comment: No need for messing about with `new Promise` - let `run` return the result of `fetch(url, options).then(...)`, and let the callback to  `then`end with `return nextLink ? this.run(nextLink) : this.aggregate`. This way an unexpected exception within the then won't result in a forever-pending promise.

Comment: @gustafc that sounds like it'll just result in a `Promise` being returned before all of the pages are fetched.

Comment: I mean think about it... if you just return fetch, and it *has* a nextLink, you return `this.run(nextLink)` which *is* a `Promise`.. wouldn't `fetcher.run().then` get a `Promise` in that case..? Also the only way to avoid a forever-pending promise in this case is to add a counter of some sort, ending prematurely isn't a desired alternative to a never-ending loop (which would technically be a problem on the API side.. as that would only happen if their data had a circular reference)

Comment: My proposition does the exact same thing your code did, but with less code - just a little suggestion for improvement. Of course it returns a promise before all pages are fetched - that's the whole idea with promises! But the promise doesn't resolve until an invocation of `run` got into the branch where`this.aggregate` is returned.

Comment: About the forever-pending promise thingy, I mis-remembered how `new Promise` handles uncaught exceptions - my bad. Still, it's always simpler to _not_ use `new Promise` unless one absolutely has to, which one only does when interfacing with callback-based APIs.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, there's a bug in the `new Promise` code which isn't present if you apply my suggestion - if the promise `fetch` (or `this.run`) returns is rejected (e.g. if the network has died), that error won't be propagated, and you have a forever-pending promise. You could fix this by passing `reject` as second argument to every `then` (or by avoiding `new Promise` in favor of letting `then` return a promise).

Comment: This is plain awesome the only issue is that in the fetch I have to go a layer deeper because on `response` the body of the response is locked also credentials need to be passed in. ```
 const options = {
  credentials: "same-origin",
  headers: {
    accept: "application/json"
  },
  timeout: 5000
};
fetch(
  "/api/v1/courses/20083/enrollments?enrollment_type=ObserverEnrollment&per_page=100",
  options
).then(response =>
  response
    .json()
    .then(data => ({
      data: data,
      ok: response.ok,
      headers: response.headers
    }))
    .then(res => {  
```

Comment: @JewellSimon you can change the options you pass into the recursively called function the same way you change the URL by pulling `res.headers.get("Link")`

Comment: Yep, I did that it works. I was just documenting that just in case other people needed

Answer (score 1):

Use async recursive functions.
I'm not exaclty sure what your api returns but this should work:
Firstly you can just return the element when you find it, it saves you a few iterations if there are too many of them.

```
function nextURL(linkTxt) {
    if (linkTxt) {
      let links = linkTxt.split(",");
      let nextRegEx = new RegExp('^<(.*)>; rel="next"$');

      for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        let matches = nextRegEx.exec(links[i]);
        if (matches && matches[1]) {
            //return right away
            return matches[1];
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Next define your main call:

```
const OPTIONS = {
  credentials: "same-origin",
  headers: {
    accept: "application/json"
  },
  timeout: 5000
};
let parents = {};
async function main(){
    const RESPONSE = await fetch(`/api/v1/courses/200003/enrollments?enrollment_type=ObserverEnrollment&per_page=100`,OPTIONS);
    let data = await RESPONSE.json();
    let res = {
        data: data,
        ok: RESPONSE.ok,
        headers: RESPONSE.headers
    }

    loop(res);
    //or: 
    //await loop(res);
    //if you want to wait for it.
}
```

And then your loop

```
const OPTIONS_NEXT = {
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      accept: "application/json"
    },
    timeout: 5000
};
async function loop(parents){
    //if nextURL returns null...
    if(nextURL(parents.headers.get("Link")),OPTIONS_NEXT === null) 
        //...end the loop
        return;
    //otherwise keep going.

    const RESPONSE = await fetch(nextURL(parents.headers.get("Link")),OPTIONS_NEXT);
    let data = await RESPONSE.json();
    let res = {
        data: data,
        ok: RESPONSE.ok,
        headers: RESPONSE.headers
    }
    if (res.ok) {
        parents.data.push(res.data);
        console.info(parents);
    }
    loop(res);
    //or: 
    //await loop(res);
    //if you want to wait for it.
    //You need to call it from within an async function.
}
```

Now all you need to do is call the main function:

```
main();
//or: 
//await main();
//if you want to wait for it.
//You need to call it from within an async function.
```

Comment: Oh I see, I'm sorry about that.
In that case you could change your nextURL function so that it returns **false** instead of **null** and test the explicit condition as **if(nextURL(parents.headers.get("Link")),OPTIONS_NEXT === false)**.

The reason you should test it as **if(condition === false)** is because **if(!condition)** actually tests true for **false** aswell as **undefined** and **null**.

Comment: Thank you @RazvanTanase. This answer is really awesome(∩_∩). This is pretty awesome as well. I tested it and it works, but the loop errors out which causes a break then leaves a hanging promise. if(nextURL(parents.headers.get("Link")),OPTIONS_NEXT === null) actually returns the api url/null changing it to if(!nextURL(parents.headers.get("Link"))) works great